# Identify heavily called function

Tags: windows-10

I search for a performance problem with procmon. This tool lists a lot of operation sequences like

```
CreateFile
QueryInformationVolume
QueryAllInformationFile
CloseFile
```

All operations are performed on the same file somewhere in the ProgramData tree. The `QueryAllInformationFile` fails with `BUFFER OVERFLOW`, the others succeed.

My first thought was that it could be related to a call of the API function `GetVolumeInformation`. But this API function rejects any call with a RootPathName that is not a drive name but a file name. Therefore it can't be used to call `QueryInformationVolume` for the file.

I have a huge amount of source code and want to identify the reason for this repeated sequence. Involved packages are e.g. the MXE cross compiler suite, some g-libraries like **glibmm**, **glibio** and others. The actual problem occurs when a program "PulseView" is running, that has been compiled with MXE.

How can I identify the API function that is responsible for the operations?

Comment: You could use WinDBG to debug the program in cause, and put a breakpoint on CreateFile or any API you want to observe, so you can see the stack trace: https://techblog.dorogin.com/windbg-how-to-set-a-breakpoint-at-win32-createfile-for-a-win64-process-a5ac952ad8be

Comment: Seems like you may find a profiler (like [Very Sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy/)) useful. Basically they pause the app very frequently and take a sample of the stacktrace. Once you have that kind of report, run when the app is showing the behaviour you want to investigate, you can look at when those functions are called and see if they have any common callers that might be the issue.